# PreparedStatement Implementation

Tags: jdbc, connection, prepared-statement

I want to check the internal working of PreparedStatement. But Connection and PreparedStatement both are interface. So how can I check the implementation of `prepareStatement(String sql)` method and `setInt` or `setString` method.

Comment: They're implemented by the JDBC driver that you're using to connect to your database. Each database has its own protocol to communicate and execute SQL statements. So, if it's open-source, you can check the source code of your database driver. But that code will be specific to your database. Why exactly do you need to know the internal workings? Isn't the contract specified in the javadoc sufficient?

Comment: @JBNizet if i am using mysql which class I have to check in mysql-connector.jar

Comment: I don't know. Use your IDE to find implementations of Connection and Statement. Read the api doc. Execute your code with your debugger and look at the class name of the instance of Connection.

Comment: Mayby the first step would be to simple issue the prepared statement and trace in the database what queries were performed.  As an next step the JDBC drive may provide option to activate logging. Details are database / drive dependent.